# Корректное завершение потоков

Tags: delphi, многопоточность, delphi-xe7

Есть класс потока:

```
TNewThread = class(TThread)
  private
    procedure Parser_auto_info(var MLQuery: TADOQuery; MTable: TADOTable);
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    MPersent, StartRegion, EndRegion, idHandle: integer;
    StartThread: boolean;
  end;
```

И объявлены в публичном разделе переменных формы три экземпляра таких:

```
var NewThread, NewThread2, NewThread3: TNewThread;
```

Запуск потока идет таким образом:

```
 // поток 1
  NewThread := TNewThread.Create;
  with NewThread do
  begin
    FreeOnTerminate:=true;
    Priority:=tpLower;
    Resume;
    idHandle:=1;
    StartRegion:=pos1Region; //1;
    EndRegion:=54;
    StartThread:=true;
  end;
```

На событие `Close` формы ставлю такой код:

```
  if NewThread.StartThread then
    try
      TerminateThread(NewThread.Handle, 0);
    finally
      NewThread.Free;
    end;
```

Он вываливает ошибку памяти. Пробовал так закрывать вместе с формой поток:

```
 if not Assigned(NewThread) then
   NewThread.Terminate;

 FreeAndNil(NewThread);
```

Пробовал прописывать еще в событие destroy формы:

```
NewThread.Free;
```

Но и это не помогает никак. Ошибки идут настойчиво, по причине того, что поток(и) некорректно закрывается. Как победить эту ошибку? Сразу говорю, что в потоке идет еще работа с базой данных, вывод данных на форму (счетчики и прогресс загрузки).

Comment: Где конструктор и деструктор? Где идёт инициализация ADO?

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, использование ADO в потоках предусматривает использование своего `TADOConnection` в каждом из потоков, поэтому передавать ADOQuery из формы уже неверно. Во-вторых, т.к. ADO - это COM, то необходимо вызывать `CoInitialize`/`CoUnitialize`:

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
   CoInitialize(nil);
   try
     try
       // Создание соединения или 
       // прямо при создании TADOQuery 
       // указать для нее ConnectionString
     except
     end;
   finally
     CoUnInitialize;
   end;
end;
```

см. [Multithreaded Delphi Database Queries](http://delphi.about.com/od/kbthread/a/query_threading.htm)

В третьих, что касается корректного завершения и осбождения, достаточно вызывать `NewThread.Terminate` из запускающего потока (по кнопке, например, или по закрытию формы). Далее поток **должен** сам завершиться, проверив `Terminated` (прервать ваш цикл). Наличие дополнительной переменной не нужно, вызывать `Free` и проч не нужно, магией заведует сам `TThread`, вы же ему явно указали `FreeOnTerminate:=True`.

Comment: Безупречный ответ. Про ADO я тоже пытался уточнить. Хотелось понять как автор инициализирует ADO. В ответе это описано проактивно. +1

Comment: Спасибо за действительно полезный ответ! И все же, судя по тому коду, что привели в ссылке, там все же ADOConnection не создается в классе потока, он загружает внешние данные от существующего коннектора. Единственное отличие от моего варианта, что таблицу в коде там создают внутреннюю и ее юзают, предварительно подключив, компонент коннектора. В остальном я делал также.

Comment: type   TCalcThread = class(TThread)   private     procedure RefreshCount;   protected     procedure Execute; override;   public     ConnStr : widestring;     SQLString : widestring;     ListBox : TListBox;     Priority: TThreadPriority;     TicksLabel : TLabel;      Ticks : Cardinal;   end;

Comment: Обратите внимание на закомментированнные строки. Эта статья о том как делать нельзя и что передавать нельзя, в частности "коннектор". // MUST USE OWN CONNECTION. `TADOConnection` создается внутри `TADOQuery` если указана строка подключения - ConnStr, т.е. внутри потока.

Comment: Ага, спасибо. Еще вопрос, сейчас пока создал пустышку в методе execute потока без цикла. CoInitialize(nil); CoUninitialize();  Выдает ошибку памяти. Подключил модуль ActiveX. С чем может вызвана такая ошибка?

Comment: Может быть вызвана кодом. Не видя кода и самой ошибки, определить не удастся.

Comment: Кода никакого нет. Просто создается поток, а в методе execute пишется CoInitialize(nil); CoUninitialize(); Никаких объектов там не создается и ничего не происходит.

Comment: По приведенному описанию ошибка не воспроизводится.

Answer (score 2):

Не надо использовать `Resume`. Этот метод, начиная по-моему с XE, подавлен (deprecated). Всесто Resume используй `Start`. Но только в том случае, если поток создан Suspended, т.е. вызван перегруженый конструктор с передачей параметра `CreateSuspended := true`

```
MyThread := TMyThread.Create(True);
...
MyThread.Start;
```

Не стоит форсированно останавливать уже запущеный поток. Это вызовет утечку ресурсов (memory leaks). На выполнение потока можно лишь *повлиять*, например, уведомить его, что ты хочешь его прервать. Поток закончится тогда, когда выполнится последний оператор в блоке `Execute` или значение `Terminated` встанет в `True` (случаи выдергивания из розетки или обесточивания микрорайона я тут не рассматриваю).

Варианты `NewThread.Free`, `NewThread = nil` хорошего результата не принесут. Такие способы могут принудительно остановить поток и вызвать блокировки ресурсов или утечки памяти.

Для того, чтобы поток корректно завершился, нужно сделать следующее:

- Дождаться окончания его выполнения *(тривиально, но это так)*
- Сказать потоку о том, что ты *просишь* его завершиться

Второй способ опишу подробнее:
Это *кооперативный* метод работы основного и дочернего потоков. Надо вызвать метод потока `Terminate`. А внутри `Execute` запрограммировать проверку свойства `Terminated`. После этого `Execute` будет периодически проверять наличие установленного свойства `Termnated` и когда оно появится, поток остановится и если стоит `FreeOnTerminate := true` корректно освободит все ресурсы (подчистит объекты, отпустит блокировки и пр.)

Comment: Совершенно некорректный ответ. Думаю, я не смогу больше принять участие в дискуссии.

Comment: Что именно Вам не нравится? Что я не объявляю и не создаю программно компоненты ADO, а использую уже те, что уже лежат на форме моего проекта или то, что про прерывание потоков есть возможность оборвать их через terminate? Лучше расскажите тогда, как классифицировать поток, который обменивается данными с формой (передает индикатор загрузки) как синхронный или асинхронный поток?

Comment: И кстати использование метода Start вообще вызывает ошибку у меня в отличие от Resume. Пишет: "Cannot call Start on a running or suspended thread. Использую XE7. Вы точно очень хорошо работали с потоками на этом делфи?

Comment: @IntegralAL Ну разумеется будет ошибка. Потому что в конструктор не передаётся параметр `CreateSuspended`, который по умолчанию равен `False`. Если вызывать конструктор через `NewThread:=TNewThread.Create(True);` тогда вызов метода `Start` не привёт к ошибке.

Comment: Создавать отдельный файл как ключ для останова потока? Что за бред? Достаточно булевой переменной же (и она уже есть - это свойство Terminated).

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, здесь я согласен. Поправлю ответ. Только свойство `Terminated` самостоятельно устанавливать не следует. Нужно вызывать метод `Terminate`.